# BlueNRG Bluetooth: how to receive data via chateractic

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, bluenrg

Currently I implement code bluetooth low engine (BLE) for STM32L476 + X-NUCLEO-IDB04A1 base on example "sensor demo".

In "Sensor Demo" example, it only code to send data to smart phone. And don't have receive data.

I think can use function below to read data:

```
tBleStatus aci_gatt_read_charac_val(uint16_t conn_handle, uint16_t attr_handle)
```

[image]

And can read data from HCI_Event_CB(hciReadPacket->dataBuff);

However I don't know how to get parameter **"uint16_t attr_handle"** for function

```
tBleStatus aci_gatt_read_charac_val(uint16_t conn_handle, uint16_t attr_handle)
```

Could you explain for me about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the value of the handle for this connection.

> When IDB04A1 successfully connects to the smart phone, it shall send a HCI_LE_META_EVENT with information for this connection. Connection_Handle can be found in the event, to be specific, a 16-byte value: 
>    (offset 6 | offset 5)

Comment: I checked and saw we can read data from EVT_VENDOR on sample_service.c